# knockout if binding working in laptops, but not working in mobile and tablet

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am trying some thing with if binding from knockout. If value is true I want to show some text and if it is false, I want to show some different text, as given in the code.
When I am opening the page with this html, I am getting the expected results.
But when I am trying to get the result in phones and in kindle tab (working fine in wondows tab), it is not giving the results for the if binding I have used in html. 
I tried removing '()' from failStatus and status in html, but it is not working. Is it any issue of binding or I am doing any thing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

```js
function temp()
{
  
     this.inviteeEmailList = ko.observableArray([]);
  
    var emailList = {};
  
    emailList['email'] = {'a@x.y , b@c.n'};
    emailList['status'] = ko.observable();
    emailList['failStatus'] = ko.observable();
  
   this.showList = function()
   {         
     for(var k in inviteeEmailList)
       {
         
         if(some_condition)
         {
       
           this.inviteeEmailList()[k]['status'](true);
           this.inviteeEmailList()[k]['failStatus'](""); 
         }
         else
           {
             this.inviteeEmailList()[k]['status'](false);
           this.inviteeEmailList()[k]['failStatus']("not exist"); 
           }
       }
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="foundEmail" data-bind="foreach : inviteeEmailList">

                <span data-bind="if: $data.status()">
                    <span>Success</span>
                </span>

                <span data-bind="if:(!$data.status() && $data.failStatus()) ">
                    <span>hello world</span>
                </span>

                <div data-bind="text:$data.email"></div>

                <div data-bind="if:!$data.status()">
                    <div data-bind="text:$data.failStatus()"></div>
                </div><br/>

            </div>
```

Comment: Can you expand on the way in which it's not working?

Comment: is this the full code?

Comment: This is the place where I am getting the trouble. I am changing the value of status and failStatus after getting response from the server, for request. It is changing the values properly after getting response. But I am not getting the proper result for mobile. @Geomorillo

Comment: have you tried the following way?
    `<!-- ko if: (!$data.status() && $data.failStatus())-->
        <span>hello world</span>
    <!-- /ko -->`

Comment: @gypsyCoder I can not use this format, because closure compiler will remove this from my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using if binding, I tried using visible binding, which worked properly for me.

Giving code below

```js
function temp()
    {
      
         this.inviteeEmailList = ko.observableArray([]);
      
        var emailList = {};
      
        emailList['email'] = {'a@x.y , b@c.n'};
        emailList['status'] = ko.observable();
        emailList['failStatus'] = ko.observable();
      
       this.showList = function()
       {         
         for(var k in inviteeEmailList)
           {
             
             if(some_condition)
             {
           
               this.inviteeEmailList()[k]['status'](true);
               this.inviteeEmailList()[k]['failStatus'](""); 
             }
             else
               {
                 this.inviteeEmailList()[k]['status'](false);
               this.inviteeEmailList()[k]['failStatus']("not exist"); 
               }
           }
       }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foundEmail" data-bind="foreach : inviteeEmailList">

      <span data-bind="visible: $data.status()">
        <span>Success</span>
      </span>

      <span data-bind="visible:(!$data.status() && $data.failStatus()) ">
        <span>hello world</span>
      </span>

      <div data-bind="text:$data.email"></div>

      <div data-bind="visible:!$data.status()">
        <div data-bind="text:$data.failStatus()"></div>
      </div><br/>

</div>
```